# how to count similar values in a column cell in data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

col1  |  col2                    | Output
2A    |  TCH_DRop,TCH_DRop,HSR   | TCH_Drop(2),HSR(1)
2B    |  HSR                     | HSR(1)
2c    |  SD_DRop,HSR             |SD_DRop(1),HSR(1)
1A    |  HSR,SD_Cong,HSR,SD_Cong |HSR(2),SD_Cong(2)

I am trying this
NOK['col2'].str.split(',').value_counts(),
but getting error

Comment: you must provide the input dataset in a reproducible format (text, or better DataFrame constructor)

Comment: how to share data set